# How to sync Google CalDAV with Evolution Calendar?

Tags: sync, evolution, calendar

I'm trying to sync a google calendar with CALENDARID@group.v.calendar.google.com to my evolution (3.22.3, last version) on my Ubuntu 16.10. If I add that as CalDAV with address "https://www.google.com/calendar/dav/ID" but it doesn't sync anything.

Can you help me? Thank you!

Comment: Please what steps did you take to get it to sync?

Comment: I went to Calendar view in Evolution, right click on right bar with Calendars' list, New Calendar -> CalDAV -> pasted link as in question (substituing ID with calendar iD) -> submitted gmail username and password when prompted. But it doesn't works.